# Reusing ansible variable causes error

Tags: ansible

Try implement some like this inside server descriptor `host_vars/MT_ora/server_vars.yml`

```
ora:
  home: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/112048
  sid: blank
  enviroment:
    ORACLE_HOME: "{{ora.home}}"
    ORACLE_SID: "{{ora.sid}}"
```

But got error:

> recursuve loop detected in template

Are there some pretty ways to reuse variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make recursions in Jinja2 expressions.
Split information you want to reuse between distinct variables:

```
ora:
  home: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/112048
  sid: blank
enviroment:
  ORACLE_HOME: "{{ora.home}}"
  ORACLE_SID: "{{ora.sid}}"
```

Here you have `ora` and `enviroment` dicts. And to define some values inside `environment` you refer `ora`.

But in your original example you try to define values inside `ora` using `ora` itself.